# JSON and XML Sanitizer in .net like OWASP Library

Tags: c#, json, xml

Anyone can provide, if there is already library/code for JSON Sanitizer and XML Sanitizer.

Found so many help on google but depends on issue solution provided, not any generic solution, if there is already library available please assist.

ex

```
string requestBody;
 using (var reader = new StreamReader(InputStream, ContentEncoding)
{
requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide specific examples you want to deal 
with and edit your question.

Comment: Please don't post irrelevant code. It doesn't help in any way, and annoys people that want to help

Comment: Why don't you simply *validate* the document? .NET's deserializer already offers a level of validation - deserialization is controlled by the XSD, so invalid documents can't be deserialized. You can specify that the XML will be validated during deserialization through XmlReaderSettings.  You can also validate documents explicitly, eg with XDocument.Validate. Sanitization is needed only when your code is writtend to read raw XML